# How to store a variable inside Redux Store in Flutter?

Tags: redux, dart, flutter, store

### Question:

How can I store a variable inside Redux store to allow other pages to access it?

### Current situation:

I am trying to store the `res` variable inside Redux store so that I can access it from any other page. This what I have done so far:

**Code:**

```js
submit(String email, String password) async {
    print(email);
    print(password);
    var data = {
        'email': email,
        'password': password
    };

    http.Response response = await http.post(
            Uri.encodeFull("http://v2mobile.dico.se/api/login"),
            body: data,
            headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        });

    var res = json.decode(response.body);
    print(res);
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I rephrased your question to start with the initial problem/question and formatted your code. There was a closing curly bracket that did not have an opening bracket so you should check the reformatted code, please. You mention "Flutter" in the tags and title but this does not show up in your question text so you may add some details about it to the question as well. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

since you don't know how redux works, I will not give you a response but I will advise you to learn redux ecosystem here is some link to start with:

[flutter-redux](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux)

examples:

[counter](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux/tree/master/example/counter)

[shopping-list-app](https://hackernoon.com/flutter-redux-how-to-make-shopping-list-app-1cd315e79b65)